# can't initialized Vue in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

i can't make run a simple Vue on my Laravel 5.4 project

i have the dependeces in package.json

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^0.8.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  },
```

I have the app.js placed on the webpack.mix

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

In my app.js i have:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */


Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#contenedorPrincipal'
});
```

Example.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        I'm an example component!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

And in my view, i have a div with id = contenedorPrincipal, in the layout and i call example in a single view..

app.blade.php

```
<div class="content-page" id="contenedorPrincipal">
    <div class="content">
        @yield('content')

    </div>
```

in the vie myview.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div>
   <example></example>
</div>
@stop
```

The npm run watch is working all the time....

When i open this view, nothing display, no error, no vue components detected from vue inspector....

i don't know what is the problem..

Comment: in your myview.blade.php are you wrapping the HTMl that you want to fill the yield slot with `@section('content')` and `@endsection`?

Comment: You can also double check that Vue is actually being booted into the window by checking that it exists on the window inside your dev console.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, i forget in my app.blade.php

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Thank you everyone!